# Почему программа делает первее то, что после rl.question()

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня на **Node.JS** есть программа, которая спаришвает: "Как тебя зовут?: ". Всё конечно работает, но после `rl.question()` у меня вызывается `console.log()` который после `rl.question`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы было всё по порядку?

Код:

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var input = readline.question('What\'s your name?: ', (name) => {
    readline.close();
    return name;
});

console.log(input);
```

Вывод:

```
What's your name?: underfined
(мой ввод.)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: См. также https://learn.javascript.ru/async — первую главу про ваш случай (Введение: колбэки) и дальнейшие главы про то, как удобнее работать с асинхронным кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как эта библиотека работает через функции обратного вызова `callback` то нужно код периписать следующим образом (имя функции конечно может быть любым, тут для ясности оставил) :

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

readline.question('What\'s your name?: ', callback);

function callback(input){
  readline.close();
  console.log(input);
}
```

Пример, с использованием функции для ввода значений. Для работы с асинхронными операциями используют `async/await` так как `await` не возможно запустить вне асинхронной функции они всегда идут вместе:

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

// таким образом можно преобразовать callback в асинхронную функцию.
const askQuestion = async( question ) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const callback = (input) => {

       // здесь можно добавить конвертацию в число если нужно
       // в функцию askQuestion передавать тип вторым параметром
       // c помощью switch можно обработать и другие типы.   

       resolve(input);
    }
    readline.question(`${question}: `, callback);
  })
}

// переменные можно хранить в любом удобном виде и месте.
let  name ="";
let  age = 0;

const run = async() => {
  name = await askQuestion('What\'s your name?');
  age =  await askQuestion('How old are you?');
  console.log(name, age);
  readline.close();
}

run()
```

Comment: А как мне сохранить данные в переменную, и после `readline.question()` вывести значение переменной?

Comment: дополнил ответ.